# How to read the module title in helper.php (Joomla 3)?

Tags: module, joomla3.0, helper

I'd like to get the module's title inside of a function in the helper.php.

```
$module->title
```

doesn't work.

I can read $module->title in the mod_xxx.php but I need this in the helper file. How to read the module title?

thanks
gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago I used approx. 1 year it will work, try this:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_countdown');

$moduleParams = new JRegistry($module->params);

print_r($module->title);
```

Comment: thanks! actually it works without the 2nd line too:
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_XXX');
    print_r($module->title);